# Transfer microsecond timestamp into table using COPY

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, copy

I need to transfer a microsecond timestamp into a table by using the COPY command.

My approach using a normal INSERT, where `X` is a timestamp (since 1.1.1970) in microseconds, looked like this:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP( X ::double precision / 100000)
```

So, an `X` of 1484579365136360 would translate to  `1/16/2017, 4:09:25.136360 PM`.

How could I do the same with the COPY command?

I expect I need to convert the timestamp before issuing the COPY command, but in what format?

Comment: Are you copying from a table to a file or from a file to a table? If it's the latter, it doesn't seem like there's an option to introduce any data transformation during the copying. I'm not an expert, though, just reading the docs and can't see how it can be done.

Comment: I'm copying from STDIN to the table with libpq. Do you know which format I could use to express a microsecond precise time which postgres is able to understand?

Comment: the easiest would be copy data as is and then add column, update it with `TO_TIMESTAMP( X ::double precision / 100000)`, drop original column and rename new to old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is normally referred as an [ETL (Extract, Transform, Load)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) process.

You want to do the transformation *withi*n the database. This is normally possible by using an *intermediate* table, where you store (as text, most probably) the data from `STDIN` via `libpq` and `COPY`.

```
COPY intermediate_table (orig_col1, orig_col2)
FROM stdin 
WITH FORMAT CSV  ;  -- Choose your parameters
```

Then transfer it to the second table by means of

```
INSERT INTO 
     dest(col1,                     col2) 
SELECT    
          f1(orig_col1, orig_col2), f2(orig_col1, orig_col2) 
FROM 
     intermediate_table ;
```

That is, you have some transforming functions on the original data to produce the data you want to store. For instance `f1` could just be your `TO_TIMESTAMP(orig_col_1 ::double precision / 100000)`.

After transforming the data from the intermediate table(s), it is common to `truncate` them (or `drop` them, and recreate them next time).